# If we face more than one error while using On Error Resume Next

Tags: vbscript, qtp

While using On Error Resume Next,it skips the encountered error and move to the next line.
If we use err.Number and err.Description it shows message and number related to the error.
My question is: what if it faces more than on error...then how it will show?

```
On Error Resume Next
    intDivideByZero
    floatDivideByZero
If err.Number <> 0 Then
    msgbox "the error number is : " & err.Number
    msgbox "the error description is : " & err.Description
End If
On error Resume 0
```

Comment: It should be `On Error Goto 0` not `On Error Resume 0`, that will trigger a Syntax Error which you are not expecting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VBScript error handling is rather limited. You will need to put an error handler after each line where an error can occur. Also, the `Err` object isn't automatically reset after an error, so you need to do that yourself. Otherwise the object will still indicate an error after the next statement, even if none occured there.

```
On Error Resume Next
intDivideByZero
If Err Then
    WScript.Echo "0x" & Hex(Err.Number) & ": " & Err.Description
    Err.Clear
End If
floatDivideByZero
If Err Then
    WScript.Echo "0x" & Hex(Err.Number) & ": " & Err.Description
    Err.Clear
End If
On Error Goto 0
```

You can simplify that a little bit by wrapping the handler in a procedure and calling that procedure after each statement:

```
Sub Trap
    If Err Then
        WScript.Echo "0x" & Hex(Err.Number) & ": " & Err.Description
        Err.Clear
    End If
End Sub

On Error Resume Next
intDivideByZero   : Trap
floatDivideByZero : Trap
On Error Goto 0
```

Comment: Is it not `On Error Goto 0`? Also specifying `On Error Goto 0` will set the `Err.Number` back to `0` without the need for `Err.Clear()`. I'm pretty sure if you run that at the moment it will fail with a syntax error.

Comment: @Lankymart Yes. But that statement is located after `floatDivideByZero`. `Err` needs to be cleared after each error (i.e. after `intDivideByZero` as well), otherwise you might get false positives (e.g. in a situation where `intDivideByZero` raised an error, but `floatDivideByZero` did not). You're right about the syntax, though. Fixed.

Comment: Yes, I realise that. My point was the statement `On Error Resume 0` was wrong to begin with. The point about `Err.Clear()` was just a nice by-product of using `On Error Goto 0` straight after a condition you wished to check for an error, I wasn't suggesting your use of it in the example code was wrong. It was more aimed at this statement in the answer - *"Also, the `Err` object isn't automatically reset after an error, so you need to do that yourself."*.

Comment: Ansgar..thanks for making me understand the concept..by such a wonderful example .. :)

Comment: @downvoter Care to explain what you deem downvote-worthy about this answer?

Comment: i didnt get u..@AnsgarWiechers

Comment: @Rupali Wasn't directed at you. Someone downvoted my answer, and I'd like to know what he/she considers wrong with it, so I can fix whatever problem there is.